# Opening and edting an password protected zip in dotnetcore

Tags: zip, .net-core, .net-core-rc2, ionic-zip

is there a way to work with password protected zip files in dotnetcore. Unfortunately System.IO.Compression does not support password protection.

So i tried to use dotnetzip, but every time i try to open an zip file i get an System.ArgumentException.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I migrated to sharpcompress and now everthing works fine. Seems that ionic zip does not work under core.

Comment: Have just created a proof of concept .Net Core 2.2 Console App, using DotNetZip  version 1.13.3 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetZip/) and can confirm that it works, having successfully created a password protected zip file.

Comment: This is correct. Me and some other people worked on migrating dotnetzip to netstandard and since release 1.13 it works correct on netcore.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to Kingpins answer, I tried ICSharpCode's SharpLibZip, which has an open issue rendering it unusable (for password protected files):
https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/issues/212

So I used the tool from the accepted answer: sharpcompress
https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress

Comment: The issue in SharpZipLib seems to be fixed now :)